# Regex for URL within string that doesn't contain "images"

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that targets URL's within a string. There are two types of URL's; image URL's and non-image URL's. I want both within one regex, like this: (image | non-image).

My regex knowledge is not really extensive yet.

The string looks like this:

```
const string = "This is a piece of text that contains https://imagecdn.com/image/1.png. It also contains https://imagecdn.com/image/1.jpg and last https://twitter.com"
```

I'd like to be able to replace all url's to be within an html  tag if it's an image and an  tag if it's a non-image URL.

Comment: So, what have you tried? Have you taken a look at regex tutotials? Have you tried writing some yet?

Comment: Yes I have tried some a lot already. Also tried to find an existing answer here. I came as far as /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/(?!images)S*)/g but i couldn't figure out how to exclude "images".

Comment: what are you trying to do?  I do not understand the last line:

"I'd like to be able to replace all url's to be within an html tag if it's an image and an tag if it's a non-image URL."

Comment: @Peter I want to use text.replace(regex, '<img src=\'$&\'/>') for instance to serve the string with the correct html tags. The goal is to serve proper html instead of plain text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the snippet below:

```js
var p = "This is a piece of text that contains https://imagecdn.com/image/1.png. It also contains https://imagecdn.com/image/1.jpg and last https://twitter.com"

var regex = /((http(s)?(\:\/\/))+(www\.)?([\w\-\.\/])*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}\/?))[^\s\b\n|]*[^.,;:\?\!\@\^\$ -]/gi;

var replaced = p.replace(regex, (matched) => {
  if (matched.includes('twitter')) {
    return `<a>${matched}</a>`
  }
  
  return `<img src=${matched}/>`
})

console.log(replaced);
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! This works great, but ideally the "twitter" url should be covered in <a></a> tags since it's not an image. Do you think that's possible?

Comment: Thanks @Peter! Works perfectly!

Comment: @Loerpert happy to help